# How do I get a Lexmark x4690 printer working?

Tags: 11.10, printing, lexmark

I m trying to get my Lexmark X4690 working, Everything was ok with Ubuntu 11.04 but since I did a clean install with 11.10, I reinstalled the Lexmark driver but I m unable to print, but the scanner works ok.

Answer (score 3):

1. First you have to install the ia32-libs, because Lexmark only offers drivers for 32-bit system:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
   ```
2. Get the [driver](http://downloads.lexmark.com/downloads/cpd/lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.tar.gz) from Lexmark and extract it anywhere you want.
3. Now, there are two options:, if you want the simple and quick way, skip to step 4, if you want to get your hands a little dirt, do the following:

   ```
   ./lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh --noexec --target

   lexmark tar xvf lexmark/instarchive_all --lzma dpkg-deb -I

   lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb mkdir raw-lexmark-archive
   dpkg-deb -e lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb

   raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN dpkg-deb -X
   lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb raw-lexmark-archive cp

   raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control
   raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control.orig sed "/^ $/d"
   raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control.orig >
   raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control rm
   raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control.orig cat
   raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control dpkg-deb -b ./raw-lexmark-archive

   New-lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.deb sudo dpkg -i
   New-lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.deb
   ```
4. Or You can get the deb package from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/w545ftercecb1vu/New-lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.deb).

Comment: Are there any advantages to doing the way in step 3, instead of the way in step 4 (besides if the downloadable `.deb` package becomes obsolete or inaccessible)?